# How to find the index of an array which has a maximum value

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of elements. If I do a `arr.max` I will get the maximum value. But I would like to get the index of the array. How to find it in Ruby

For example

```
a = [3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34]
=> [3, 6, 774, 24, 56, 2, 64, 56, 34]
>> a.max
a.max
=> 774
```

I need to know the index of that `774` which is `2`. How do I do this in Ruby?

Comment: This question is equivalent to part of the question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656677/how-do-i-find-a-integer-max-integer-in-an-array-for-ruby-and-return-the-indexed-p

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
a.index(a.max)  should give you want you want
```

Comment: This will go through the array twice though.

Comment: At least in Python, it's faster to go through the array twice in functions written in C than it is to be more clever in interpreted code: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2011/06/14/the-language-interpreters-are-the-new-machines/

Comment: is iterating through the array with each and using a comparison to keep track of the current max faster than this solution?

Answer (score 28):

In 1.8.7+ `each_with_index.max` will return an array containing the maximum element and its index:

```
[3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34].each_with_index.max #=> [774, 2]
```

In 1.8.6 you can use `enum_for` to get the same effect:

```
require 'enumerator'
[3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34].enum_for(:each_with_index).max #=> [774, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

that should work

```
[7,5,10,9,6,8].each_with_index.max
```